# How to add multiple checkboxes and radiobuttons in document using docusign REST API

Tags: docusignapi

I am trying to send checkboxes and radio buttons in my pdf. when I select one checkbox all the checkboxes are getting checked. how can I add multiple checkboxes 
I am using Anchor strings to place the checkbox tab . Also i want checkbox left to the string how can i set Xoffset and Yoffset.

Comment: That is happening because you are assigning each checkbox with the same "Name" value. Make them each unique. Regarding the x/y offset, please check the documentation (REST API example) https://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/RESTAPIGuide.htm#REST%20API%20References/Tabs/Checkbox%20Tab.htm?Highlight=checkbox

Comment: Please post the `JSON` (or `XML`) body that you are sending to create your checkboxes and radiobuttons.  The problem will be apparent in there.

Answer (score 1):

In the `<tabs>` element, the `<tabLabel>` tag is used to group the elements together. If you need to have the checkboxes to react separately from one other, the value for the `<tabLabel>` element needs to be different between multiple checkbox tabs.

The [soap API guide](https://www.docusign.com/p/APIGuide/APIGuide.htm#Sending%20Group/Tab.htm?Highlight=radio%20button) for DocuSign says:

> Making custom tab’s TabLabel the same will cause the all like fields
>   to update when the user enters data. When using this option, the
>   TabLabel must not contain any spaces.